# Positioning a drawingview on top of a Scrollview

Tags: .net, maui

I'm trying to position the drawing view to be on top of the Scroll View but still be in the same location. I want to do this so once a user puts his finger in the drawing view it begins to draw, right now there is a delay, and you have to hold your finger down for a second to recognize the action. Things I have tried:

1. Tried to set the Z-Index of the Drawing View to be on the highest level.
2. I tried every gesture recognizer I could put on the Drawing View. Then tried to disable the scroll view on said gesture. But it seems they are not triggered like they should be.

Anyone have any idea on how I could position the Drawing View over the Scroll view but be in the same location?

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="EaaDigitalSigningApp.Views.YeMinorWaiverPage"
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
         Shell.BackgroundColor="{StaticResource EaaBlue}"
         Title="Waiver Page">

<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
    <BackButtonBehavior Command="{Binding BackCommand}"/>
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>


<ScrollView x:Name="SigningScrollView" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" WidthRequest="800" IsEnabled="True" >
    <Grid Padding="20,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- The Contract Itself. -->
        <WebView x:Name="Webview" InputTransparent="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HeightRequest="1825"  VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        
        <toolkit:DrawingView x:Name="drawingView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"   BackgroundColor="BlanchedAlmond"  
            DrawingLineCompleted="DrawingView_DrawingLineCompleted" HeightRequest="200" Lines="{Binding Signature}" IsMultiLineModeEnabled="True"
            ShouldClearOnFinish="False" />
        

        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding  parentSignatureText}" x:Name="ParentSignatureText" FontSize="Micro" />

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start">
            <Label x:Name="ParentOrGuardiansPrintedName" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Text="{Binding YeWaiver.Signee.FullNameFirstLast}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding PrintParentSignatureText}" x:Name="PrintParentSignatureText" FontSize="Micro" />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Label x:Name="MinorParticipantsPrintedName" Text="{Binding YeWaiver.Signee.AssociatedMinorFullNameFirstLast}" />
            <Label Text="Minor Participant's Name" IsVisible="{Binding MinorSignatureTextVisible}" x:Name="MinorSignatureText" FontSize="Micro"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Label x:Name="DateOfSignature" Text="{Binding ContractDate}"/>
            <Label Text="Date" FontSize="Micro" VerticalOptions="Start" />
        </StackLayout>


        <Button Grid.Row="4" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontSize="Large" x:Name="ReviewAndSignDocument" Text="Complete Signing And Next Document" Command="{Binding ReviewAndSignCommand}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource EaaBlue}" TextColor="White" />
        <Button Grid.Row="5" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  FontSize="Large" x:Name="SkipDocument" Text="Skip this Youth >>" IsVisible="{Binding SkipDocumentVisible}" IsEnabled="{Binding SkipDocumentEnabled}"  Command="{Binding SkipDocumentCommand}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource EaaBlue}" TextColor="White"  />

    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: the DrawingView is a child of the scrollview, you can't place it on top of it's parent

Answer (score 0):

You can either make `Grid` or `AbsoluteLayout` as your root element. Here's how you can do it with `Grid`. How it works, both `ScrollView` and `DrawingView` are targetting the same grid location `Grid.Row="0"` `Grid.Column="0"`:

```xml
<ContentPage>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollView>
        </ScrollView>
        <toolkit:DrawingView>
        </toolkit:DrawingView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```